# How to set Auxiliary Control Register bit on Cortex M4

Tags: cortex-m

My application running on a Cortex M4 is crashing with a hard fault. The CSFR register indicates `IMPRECISERR`.

Reading http://chmorgan.blogspot.nl/2013/06/debugging-imprecise-bus-access-fault-on.html I am advised to set the `DISDEFWBUF` bit in the Auxiliary Control Register (ACTLR). This will allow me to get `PRECISERR` which are easier to debug.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By reading the [programming manual](http://www.st.com/content/ccc/resource/technical/document/programming_manual/6c/3a/cb/e7/e4/ea/44/9b/DM00046982.pdf/files/DM00046982.pdf/jcr:content/translations/en.DM00046982.pdf)
[image: ACTLR] for our CPU, we can see the ACTLR is at address `0xE000 E008`, and the `DISDEFWBUF` bit is `1`.

In `main`, this bit can be set with the following code:

```
*(uint8_t *)0xE000E008 |= (1<<i);
```

Where `i = 1;`

Comment: CMSIS has standard defines for this register. Use ``SCnSCB->ACTLR |= SCnSCB_ACTLR_DISDEFWBUF_Msk`` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Change the value in SFRs pallete. STM32f429,Register:

[image: STM32f429,Register]

Read [this article](https://www.beningo.com/how-to-debug-a-hard-fault-on-an-arm-cortex-m/) for more information.